# Log4j2 Dynamically setting the log directory during tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, log4j2

This problem seems to be so incredibly simple, but I've been working for hours trying to solve it and come up with nothing.

I have build a test framework using Selenium and Testng. I have a base class that gets extended to any test class that is created and this base class is responsible for a few different function one of which is creating a uniquely named directory where I am storing  my screenshots from tests. This functionality works fine. The problem is that I am now trying to integrate log4j2 into the test framework and what I want is for these logs to be written to a file inside of this unique directory that is created with each run. Here is what my log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logFilename">${sys:logFileName}</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="${logFilename}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As you can see I'm attempting to use use the property `${sys:logFileName}` where `logFileName` is defined in my base class like this:

```
        // Seting the log file path programmatically
        // resultsDirName is the path to the unique directory that is being created
        // at the start of each test.
        String logFilePath = resultsDirName + "/test.log";
        System.out.println(logFilePath);
        System.setProperty("logFileName", logFilePath);
```

When I run my test here is the error that I get:

```
ERROR StatusConsoleListener FileManager (../${sys:logFileName}) java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
 java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I know the path is correct, because the directory is being created and I am successfully saving my screenshots there. It's also important to note that I am not initializing the logger until after these sys variable have been created. I have tried a few other things that had some unexpected results. For example if I change my log4j2.xml to have this line:
`<Property name="logFilename">${logFileName}</Property>`
I end up with a log file created in my project root that is actually called ${logFileName}.

I have also tried the following in my xml:

```
        <Property name="logDirectory">${logDirectory}</Property>
        <Property name="logFilename">${logDirectory}/test.log</Property>
    </Properties>
```

Once again this is actually creating a directory called `${logDirectory}` and storing the log file there. I also get this error:
`WARN StatusConsoleListener Infinite loop in property interpolation of logDirectory`

I feel like a complete fool. I'm building a similar test framework in python and had zero issues implementing this feature. I don't understand why this is so hard and convoluted in java, or perhaps it's just because I'm more of a novice in Java. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `${sys:logFileName}` is resolved to `${sys:logFileName}` it means that Log4j Core is initialized **before** you set the system property. You can set both `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and `-Dlog4j2.loggerContextStacktraceOnStart=true` to pinpoint the moment the backend is initialized. This could be:

- an explicit call to one of the `LogManager` methods,
- one of your libraries initializes a logging API that is bridged to Log4j API.

#### Sequential tests

If you are **not** running your tests in parallel, you can easily ignore this problem by:

- setting a nice default value for the log file if the system property is not present:

  ```xml
  <Properties>
      <Property name="logFilename">./target/logs/global.log</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
      <File name="File" fileName="${sys:logFilename}">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      </File>
  </Appenders>
  ```
- after you set your system variable just reconfigure Log4j Core:

  ```java
  Configurator.reconfigure();
  ```

  No log events will be lost during this time, although some of them might end up in the old and new log file.

#### Parallel tests

**Parallel** tests are hard for most applications, since they usually use **static** loggers, so you can not just spawn a different `LoggerContext` per test (as it is done in Log4j Core own tests). The best results in this case could be obtained using a `RoutingAppender` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71455641/11748454)), which decides where to send a log event based on a thread-bound value. You can use `ThreadContext` and the `${ctx:...}` lookup for this.

#### Remark

You can of course combine the two approaches by using a `RoutingAppender` that checks `${sys:logFilename}` at each message. You will not need a reconfiguration in this case, but performance might suffer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used log4j2, but I guess you're better of with programmatic configuration. Described here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html