# Log4j how to create separate log file for each test?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, log4j

I have BaseClass that has @BeforeClass method and uses `Configurator.initialize(null, "log4j2.xml");`, here is my log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogFile" fileName="src//test//resources//logs/application.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How to approach it as every method found on internet didn't work?

I tried System.setProperty and of two tests it made second test log file and put there all logs including from the first test.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As part of your question you should detail everything that you tried that didn't work and what were the actual issues with those solutions. Note that this is an unusual use case for log4j. There are no guarantees log4j supports it.

Comment: @aled What do you mean it's unusual? People use one log file for all executed tests?

Comment: I don't know what people do for tests but I believe it is unusual for log4j to log to different files in the way you describe.

Comment: @aled So let's say I have many classes that execute big tests so it's unusual to put each test logs in a separate log file?

Comment: One log file per class? Not usual in my experience, but other people may have different experiences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4j2 Dynamically setting the log directory during tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098810/log4j2-dynamically-setting-the-log-directory-during-tests)

Comment: Check also an example of [`RoutingAppender` configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71455641/11748454).